# Linked List Not Printing Out Correct Data

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm having trouble understanding why my printout method for my linked list implementation does not work. When the linked list has the numbers 1-5, it prints out 0è⌂è⌂ using the following code below:

```
void printList(List& source, bool forward)
{
    
    if (forward)
    {
        ListItr start = ListItr(source.first());
        while (!start.isPastEnd())
        {
            cout << start.retrieve() +" ";
            start.moveForward();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ListItr end = ListItr(source.last());
        while (!end.isPastBeginning())
        {
            cout << end.retrieve() + " ";
            end.moveBackward();
        }    
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

However, with my past implementation, it works just fine and I am confused as to why because they are identical but just with different variable placements.

```
void printList(List &source, bool forward){

  ListItr itr;

  if(forward)
  {
    itr = ListItr(source.first());

    while(!itr.isPastEnd())
    {
      cout << itr.retrieve() << " ";

      itr.moveForward();
    }

  }
  else
  {
    itr = ListItr(source.last());

    while(!itr.isPastBeginning())
    {
      cout << itr.retrieve() << " ";

      itr.moveBackward();
    }

  }

  cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you try to add return value of `itr.retrieve()`and `" "` that value is 32 as a decimal in ASCII. I mean, your fail code;

```
cout << start.retrieve() +" ";
```

your worked code;

```
cout << itr.retrieve() << " ";
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you, I would have never found that error as I am more inclined to using java haha.

Comment: @J4102 And that is the danger of using Java or any other programming language, as a model in writing C++ code.  Not only do mistakes like this happen, the C++ code becomes either buggy, hard to read, or just plain weird looking to a C++ programmer.